# Finding Objects Views Or Tables From JavaScript Based Procedure Definition

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find out The Objects Referred In Snowflake Based JavaScript Based  Procedure, I tried RegEX methods of fining out Table Objects Used Inside DML Dialects . Using RegEx is very crude way of finding what are DML based Objects Inside JAVASCRIP Based Definitions. It might  sometime work and may not work too.

this looks like Language Parsing technique where we tokenize the Procedure Definition and search out DML objects using  String Tokenization.

Has any one tried this approach or is there any best approach to this technique .

P.S. Moderator Please do not close this subject , there is no feature of finding Objects referred in Procedure Definition ; hence i am trying to find out different perspectives ways to get this done.

Comment: Please ask questions that can be reproduced: What you want, what you have tried, what you got instead. If we can reproduce, we can improve what you have.

Comment: Hi @Felipe Hoffa, I  tried Reg Ex pattern with Loop Back Assertions (?<=INSERT INTO|UPDATE | MERGE INTO).*, for confidential purpose i can't put  the full RegEx pattern here ,  through out Procedure definition Developer can try to bind Input Params to SQL String such as DELETE FROM ${DB}.{SCHEMA}.{TABLE}; but you see this is not actually table value but it is table to be built  during runtime using input paramas or static variable values coming from Procedure definition, I would like to read Variables  such as DB, SCHEMA & TABLE from Procedure definition.